# How to handle texture animation in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, sdl, glew

I started using OpenGL with SDL2 and GLEW not so long ago, and I got two questions:

- How to pass a texture to GLSL's uniform sampler2D ? It seems to do it automatically when binded, but it confuses me.

And the main question here:

- What's the best way to handle texture animation? 
  Should I do it by GL_TEXTURE_3D? By loading all frames into multiple GL_TEXTURE_2D? Is there a built-in way for animation?

Comment: *"How to pass a texture to GLSL's uniform"* Set `sampler2D` as if it was an `int`. Assign texture slot index to it (i.e. if the texture you want is bound to `GL_TEXTUREi`, use `i`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glActiveTexture and glBindTexture calls in this order will bind a texture to the given sampler slot.

Use a spritesheet as a TEXTURE_2D, and change the texture coordinates for swapping the animation frames.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, it helped me put my thoughts back in order. I guess I'm going for a spritesheet then! Does this mean that there's no built-in feature to accomplish texture based animations though?

Comment: I dont think so, but its really not needed, the method i described is simpler than it sounds.